# Supress FreeBSD "link down: cable prοblem?" messages

Tags: networking, freebsd, ethernet

I have a FreeBSD lab machine that is regularly connected and disconnected from the network, sometimes to borrow the port temporarily for another machine and other times to test the ability of certain software to recover from losing the network connection.  It is possible for the machine to be disconnected for several hours at a time.

When I do this, I get screens (and log files) full of `de0: link down: cable problem?`.

There is some discussion about this on [this email list](http://www.sunmanagers.org/pipermail/sunmanagers/2006-April/040127.html) in 2006, but there is no solution posted.  As that questioner said [in a follow-up](http://www.sunmanagers.org/pipermail/sunmanagers/2006-April/040128.html), I do not want to disable the interface every time.

---

**Note**: [The Question Title filter prevents the word "problem" from appearing in the title of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles), hence the non-English character in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this issue, by [compiling and installing a custom kernel](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html).

Edit the file /usr/src/sys/dev/de/if_de.c, disabling the following line

```
device_printf(sc->tulip_dev, "link down: cable problem?\n");
```

as follows:

```
#ifdef CABLE_MESSAGES
device_printf(sc->tulip_dev, "link down: cable problem?\n");
#endif
```